# What is the meaning of "not another"?

Tags: meaning

What does 'not another' mean in a sentence?

For example:

> Tom misspelled the word and I pointed the word out. Then another man who was watching said "not another!!"  A bystanding girl laughed.

What does the "not another" in this sentence mean?

Comment: Perhaps you can give some context in which it was used? I can think of a few different contexts where it would mean different things.

Comment: It is still unclear what you are asking. Since the phrase *not another* is not humorous in and of itself, it is not clear why the phrase would make the other girl laugh.

Comment: I don't know why she laughed but I guess "not another" is short for "It's not another person's problem.". Is this right?

Comment: The way I read it was "Oh, not _another_ one!" and it could mean "not another spelling mistake!" or it could mean not another mistake pointed out. It's still not clear to me and I don't have a FaceBook account, so I can't see the contents of your link.

Comment: Your Facebook link doesn't go anywhere, so we can't see the comment you're talking about. Can you copy the text into your question?

Answer (score 1):

This expression is usually used to express displeasure with a repeating pattern when you see one more instance.  For example, if someone was correcting a text that I wrote and found a lot of errors, I could say "not another" to mean that I was upset with how many errors I made.  I think that that is the most likely explanation here, and it means "not another mistake."  I don't have the full context though, and it could be something else.